# iOS GestureRecognizers All Directions

Tags: ios

I am fairly new to iOS development. I have just started about a month or two ago. I have an idea for an application, but it would require Gesture Recognizers. I have looked for the documentation for Gesture Recognizers but as far as I can tell, it can only detect 4 directions. Up, left, right, and down. Is there anyway to write some code that will let you detect any direction the user swipes. For example, if the user were to swipe towards the upper-right direction or bottom-right direction, is there a way to detect that?

EDIT: After thinking about this I have come up with a better way to explain what I need code for. If I was developing a game for iOS and the user is usually in a camera view (birds-eye view) and I wanted to allow them to move their view in a map so that they could perhaps view an enemy's base or their ally's base, how would I detect those diagonal swipes rather than just up, right, left, and down swipes?

Comment: Why not use a UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Comment: No, because how would you define that?  You can create your own gesture recognizer and try, though.

Comment: Well, I have seen some keyboards on Android like Swype in which you can swipe your fingers across the keyboard and a line will appear on the screen and follow the movement of your finger. Is there a way to replicate something like this on iOS and then I will just find the first point the user touched and the last point the user touched and then do calculations to find the slope which will give me the direction the user swiped in?

Comment: `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a little confused.

`UISwipeGestureRecognizer` is a subclass of `UIGestureRecognizer`, and, as you say, it only detects swipes for those 4 directions.

But then there's `UIPanGestureRecognizer` which you can use to detect movement in any direction. It gives you a method called `translationInView:` which gives you just that, the change of the position of your finger in whichever direction.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across your question, since it was something similar to what I wanted to do, but then ended up not using it. So I figured I'd leave the code here for posterity. Just use an UIPanGestureRecognizer and set a method similar to this one for your target/selector:

```
typedef enum {
    NONE = 0,
    LEFT = 1,
    RIGHT = 2,
    UP = 4,
    DOWN = 8
} BLDirection;

-(void)detectDirection:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)pan {
    if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        CGPoint stopPan = [pan translationInView:self.view];
        CGPoint velocity = [pan velocityInView:self.view];

        int direction = NONE;

        // first determine the directions
        if (velocity.x < 0) {
            direction |= LEFT;
        } else if (velocity.x > 0) {
            direction |= RIGHT;
        }

        if (velocity.y < 0) {
            direction |= UP;
        } else if (velocity.y > 0) {
            direction |= DOWN;
        }

        // now we figure out the angle of the swipe
        double x2 = stopPan.x;
        double x1 = 0;
        double y2 = abs(stopPan.y);
        double y1 = 0;

        // angle is in degrees
        double angle = atan((y2 - y1 + 1) / (x2 - x1 + 1)) * 57.29577951308233; // 180/pi

        // mask out the vertical directions if they aren't sufficiently strong
        if ((angle < 0 && angle < -55) || (angle > 0 && angle > 55)) {
            direction &= (UP | DOWN);
        }

        // mask out the horizontal directions if they aren't sufficiently strong
        if ((angle < 0 && angle > -35) || (angle > 0 && angle < 35)) {
            direction &= (LEFT | RIGHT);
        }

        NSLog(@"Direction is %s%s%s%s", ((direction & UP) == UP) ? "UP" : "",
              ((direction & DOWN) == DOWN) ? "DOWN" : "",
              ((direction & LEFT) == LEFT) ? "LEFT" : "",
              ((direction & RIGHT) == RIGHT) ? "RIGHT" : "");

        // do something here now that you know the direction. The direction could be one of the following:
        // UP
        // DOWN
        // LEFT
        // RIGHT
        // UP|LEFT
        // UP|RIGHT
        // DOWN|LEFT
        // DOWN|RIGHT
    }
}
```